# Unable to compile fmem_1.6-0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I have been trying to perform memory acquisition of Ubuntu 16.04 running in VirtualBox. I am aware of LiME as an option but would also like to use fmem which has failed to compile on my machine. I know that compiling fmem on the box under investigation is not advised but this is just a lab environment.

Details of the machine

```
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0$ uname -a
Linux u64-VirtualBox 4.10.0-27-generic #30~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 16:07:46 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0$
```

List of kernel headers installed

```
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic              3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-31-generic              3.16.0-31.43~14.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.35-031635-generic         3.16.35-031635.201605011734                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.35 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-27-generic              4.10.0-27.30~16.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic               4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-27-generic        4.10.0-27.30~16.04.2                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic         4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04              4.10.0.27.30                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0$
```

Make Command gives the following error

```
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0$ make
rm -f *.o *.ko *.mod.c Module.symvers Module.markers modules.order \.*.o.cmd \.*.ko.cmd \.*.o.d
rm -rf \.tmp_versions
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.o
/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.c: In function ‘memory_lseek’:
/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.c:289:42: error: ‘struct inode’ has no member named ‘i_mutex’
  mutex_lock(&file->f_path.dentry->d_inode->i_mutex);
                                          ^
/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.c:310:44: error: ‘struct inode’ has no member named ‘i_mutex’
  mutex_unlock(&file->f_path.dentry->d_inode->i_mutex);
                                            ^
/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.c: In function ‘memory_open’:
/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.c:348:19: error: ‘struct address_space’ has no member named ‘backing_dev_info’
    filp->f_mapping->backing_dev_info =
                   ^
/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.c:349:6: error: ‘directly_mappable_cdev_bdi’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     &directly_mappable_cdev_bdi;
      ^
/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.c:349:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0/lkm.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/u64/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-27-generic'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'fmem' failed
make: *** [fmem] Error 2
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/f/fmem_1.6-0$
```

Comment: were you able to compile it?